# Using "former" in a relative clause

Tags: pronouns, relative-clauses

I wrote:

> Telegram is almost like mixing Twitter and WhatsApp, which the former is banned in Iran.

I mean just Twitter is banned.
Did I use "former" correctly? Or perhaps it is *from which the former*.

Comment: "which the former" is ungrammatical.  ... *the former of which* is banned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use of former is grammatical in the sentence, but there should be "of" in front of "which". You can also say ......, the former of which is banned in Iran.  However, it's more appropriate to split the sentence into two sentences.

Telegram is almost like mixing Twitter and WhatsApp.  The former is banned in Iran.